# Which C++11 compilers for Windows support new type traits like "is_nothrow_move_constructible"?

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, type-traits

Is there any C++11 compiler for Windows that supports the new C++11 type traits, like `is_nothrow_move_constructible`?

I was trying to write a container that supported it, only to find that none of my compilers (VC++ 2010, TDM MinGW32 GCC 4.6) support it...

Comment: Can't you simply have GCC 4.7? But I don't know if it supports is_nothrow_*.

Comment: @Geoffroy: I could, but is there one for Windows? The latest one I saw was 4.6.

Comment: I just checked and GCC and is_nothrow_move_constructible is supported in the library, so you can use it. And of course there is one for Windows ! You already get a compiler, so if CygWin doesn't have it yet  just check http://gcc.gnu.org/install/ (there may be some binary available somewhere)

Comment: @Geoffroy: Ohhh, I completely forgot about Cygwin... I always use MinGW. I hate using Cygwin in general, but I wouldn't mind it here; thanks for reminding me about it!

Comment: @JesseGood do you also happen to know where to get clang pre built binaries for windows?

Comment: @Mr.Anubis: [rubenvb](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/rubenvb/) keeps some personal builds of clang also (see win64 if you want the 64-bit version).

Comment: @JesseGood: Wow, that's fantastic. Please post it as an answer! It looks like it has exactly what I need. :)

Comment: @JesseGood: While we're on this topic... I'm really confused about the naming. Is something like `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc-4.7.1-2-release-win64_rubenvb` a compiler for a 64-bit or 32-bit host? What about the target? (Or are they multilib?) They have so many x86/x64's in the name that I can't tell what the names mean, I always have to download them to figure them out... >_<

Comment: @Mehrdad: Did you see the readme.txt file? The one you are referring to is 64-bit.

Comment: @Mehrdad: nuwen's MinGW distro is currently at gcc 4.7.1: http://nuwen.net/mingw.html

Comment: @JesseGood x64 build doesn't seems to work as he posted, I'm better stick with x32 , thanks

Comment: @JesseGood: Ah, nope, I didn't even know it existed until I scrolled lower lol... thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For mingw, I would recommend [STL's distro here](http://nuwen.net/mingw.html) (gcc 4.7.1). It comes with boost 1.50 also.

There also is mingw-w64 (a fork of the original mingw), I recommend [rubenvb's personal builds here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/rubenvb/). Go to `Toolchains targetting Win32` if you want the 32-bit versions. He also has personal builds of clang (clang support on windows is still very buggy. The x64 build will report linker errors so can only be used for better diagnostics, etc.)

STL's distro is very nice, however I find the mingw-w64 to have much better support for the win32 api (I have run into countless problems with the original mingw) and c++11 headers, such as `<atomic>` which is unsupported in the original mingw. mingw-w64 is much more actively developed (can create 32-bit and 64-bit binaries) and includes support for newer functions from windows vista and up.

For more info on the naming conventions of mingw-w64, [see here](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/mingw-w64/wiki/download%20filename%20structure) and the [faq](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/mingw-w64/wiki/FAQ).

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio C++ 2012 Beta supports a lot of C++11 type traits according to the reference. Have a look at [the Visual Studio C++ 2012 Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb982077) However, I could not find `is_nothrow_move_constructible` documented there. It appears to be supported though.

Comment: Does it *actually* support it, or does it simply return `true`?

Comment: Visual Studio 2012 RTM appears to support `is_nothrow_move_constructible`. (RTM is available to MSDN subscribers -it also looks like evaluation downloads for the RTM are available to everyone as well).

Comment: It could offer *partial* support, say returning is_pod or is_trivial.

Comment: Stephan T. Lavavej has indicated that they "intend to completely support the C++11 Standard Library, modulo not-yet-implemented compiler features" (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx).  I don't think that `is_nothrow_move_constructible` would depend on C++11 features that aren't in VC++11.  So if `is_nothrow_move_constructible` doesn't work correctly, I'd think they'd consider it a bug (not that that would help you use it today).

Comment: @NicolBolas: For me, it returns `true` even for a type that can throw from its move constructor. Recompiling my test under VS2013 correctly gives `false`. Bug!

Answer (score 1):

GCC 4.7 does support is_nothrow_move_constructible you can try it on Windows by installing  [MinGW Distro](http://nuwen.net/mingw.html).

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but I just learned something from looking at the source code of GCC 4.7's `type_traits` header:

You don't even *need* `is_nothrow_xyz` in the first place!

The `noexcept` operator tells you if an exception throws.
So for these *specific* type traits, you can use that instead.

(Or at least in theory. Whether your compiler implements it is another matter.)